# What may have happend to this arduino NANO?

Tags: safety, voltage-protection

Accidentally I just short circuit my arduino nano, using a led neopixel, between the 5vOutput with one of the data pins.

Now the pc doesnt recognize the device when I connect it.
In the device (a NANOV3.0).

[image]
Only the PWR(POWER/ON) led is light up, while L light doesn't. Using the multimeter VoltsDC(20), between the ground (USB) and the pin 5v it just give me 2 Volts

What may it be? How should I chek it? It is possible to fix changing a microcomponent?
Thank you

Comment: Before tearing your hair out much about this further I would disconnect it. Shut the machine off, wait a while, turn it on, and see if the voltage is more normal (well above 2V) again.

Comment: @timemage thank you for your suggestion, I checked out again and is still in 2 volts (1.99 to be more accurate) Do you have another idea? Or at least do you know any video tutorial which show how to test with a multimeter with section may be malfunctioning?. The led in the power it isn't at the full original brighness tho, it is like, 50%.

Comment: Nothing coming to mind that I can turn into an answer. I just wanted to make sure your was not effectively self healing.

Comment: the device is double sided ... you posted a picture of only one side

Comment: Seems like there is damage. You might want to compare with a working Nano. What voltage is at the "3V3" pin? Did you look up the schematic to get ideas what could be dead?

Comment: There is stepdown chip and diode on the other side. Most time diode is blown and shorting VCC. Or maybe stepdown is blown as well. Show us picture from bottom side

Comment: Tell in more detail please how the Neopixel was connected, and for how long, and what else happened. Also measure all supply voltage pins (5V, 3.3V, Vin) against GND pin and tell us.